# Sort hash by column in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, printf

I have an associative array that I'm printing out and sorting, but the sort command is doing something funny.

```
for i in "${!hash[@]}"; do
    printf "%'d %s\n" "${hash[$i]}" "$i"
done | sort -rn -k1
```

It's supposed to sort by the integer in the first column, but instead it sorts it by the first digit instead.  Output example:

```
505 root
2 games
1 bin
17 adm
1,325 mail
```

How can I make it sort by the whole number, instead of the first digit?

Comment: what's your input `hash` looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
sort -rn -k1
```

with

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort -rn
```